# Executing a char or string in Forth as though it was a word

Tags: forth, gforth

Let's say I have `s" Hello"` stored somewhere. and I've also defined `: Hello something ;`. Is there a way to execute the string as though it was the word?

I've read the documentation, but I cannot find any relevant functionality. It might be obvious, but alas I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on my system.

```
s" Hello" EVALUATE
```

Comment: I hate that i didn't find this. I spent so long.. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

NB: [`EVALUATE`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/EVALUATE) [interprets](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#section.3.4) (translates) a string. It means that in compilation state your "Hello" will be **compiled**. E.g.:

```
: foo s" hello" evaluate ;
: [foo] foo ; immediate


: hello ." something" ;
: bar [foo] ; \ "hello" will be compiled into bar

bar \ will execute hello
```

Another way is to use [`SEARCH-WORDLIST`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/search/SEARCH-WORDLIST) or [`FIND-NAME`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/FIND#reply-174) words, e.g.:

```
s" hello" find-name dup ?nf name> execute
```

Where

```
find-name ( c-addr u -- nt|0 ) \ returns a name token nt or 0
?nf ( nt|0 -- ) \ throws an exception on zero, i.e. not found
name> ( nt -- xt )
```

The last two can be defined in Gforth as

```
: ?nf ( x|0 -- ) if exit then -13 throw ;
: name> ( nt -- xt|0 )
  dup name>interpret swap name>compile drop over = if exit then drop 0
;
```

Comment: My main use for EVALUATE has been to create immediate words to use at compile time.   Often variations on 'start a do loop' in one word and 'end loop' in another, allowing me for example to loop through a list with `list{ ... }list` using `i` as the item address in the loop.

Comment: If in compilation state you need to compile a text from the input source — `evaluate` is the right method. But usually you need a [hygienic macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygienic_macro). In such case `postpone` or `compile,` could be more suitable.